# HTML - Including absolute path for JS files

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting an absolute path for a JS file like this in an HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Public/myapp/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in my browser. My document root is `C:\Users\Public\myapp\public`

Though the JS file exists outside the document root, I need to include it.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use the relative path `/js/jquery.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute paths are not good when you are uploading to the shared server or to a server where you don't know the website directory paths. (Its not difficult to find out - but when this is uploaded by someone else or re-uploaded to new server - you will again need to update all references).

But you can use something like this:

```
../PATH-TO-FILE
```

Or for the above script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../myapp/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

which takes you one or two directories back of the file system.